# Why is my Arc theme not looking correct on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, themes, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I want to switch to Linux. So I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS besides Windows 10.
So I'm an absolute beginner.

Today I installed the Arc theme and then I installed Tweaks to change the theme:
[image]

This is how the dock looks right now:
[image]
<sup>(click to enlarge)</sup>

But on the screenshots on the internet, the Arc theme has a nice dock. This is what I wanted:
[image]

Can someone tell me, why my dock looks standard?

**After doing what the accepted answer says:**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu dock's style is dictated by your chosen GNOME shell theme. Looks like you have just selected Arc as only the '*Applications*' theme, but not as the shell theme also.

First you'll have install and activate [**User Themes**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) shell extension (refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481)).

Then you may use **(GNOME) Tweaks** to change the shell theme. Open Tweaks and go to **Appearance** section. Under '*Themes*' you'll be able to select Arc:

[image]